# Link Protocol Buffer libraries to Visual Project

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

I am trying to link the protocol buffer libraries to my Visual Studio (Studio Express 2013) project. But I am getting linking errors such as `error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "private: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::SetCachedSize(int)const " (?SetCachedSize@Message@protobuf@google@@EBEXH@Z)`

I did the following:

1. Build the protocol buffer libraries by the protobuff.sln solution in release mode (/MD).
2. Generate the protocol buffer includes with the extract_includes.bat
3. Copy the libraries to the lib folder in my project
4. Copy the includes to the includes folder in my project
5. Add the path for liraries and includes in my project properties
6. Create a example.proto with a string attribute
7. Compile the example.proto into example.pb.h and example.pb.cc
8. Add these two files to my src folder in my project

For information:

- The project includes Boost as well. I am using Asio to manage the communication on the C++ side.
- I would like to transfer messages containing an array of double, an integer and a string

I do not really know what else to try in order to make my project link correctly...
If someone has any idea, it will be really helpful. Thanks.

If we do not find a solution, I will try to serialize my objects into JSon (gson for Java, and manual serialization on C++ side).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why is this question tagged with `java`?

Comment: @Simon, i guess because of the reference in the last couple of lines.... not sure it is a correct tag for the question though

Comment: Thank you. I added a java tag because the question takes place in a C++/Java communication context. You know better than me how to tag the subject, so let's remove the Java tag (since to be already done).